# Compare two dates from user input on form

Tags: php

I'm trying to compare two dates from user input using datepicker.

1. If the input is `$start-date > $end-date`, it will show an error message.
2. My problem is, when user input eg. `$start-date: 30-11-2015` and `$end-date: 01-12-2015`, it will also show the error. The input supposed to be correct and not to display the .error message.
3. Need help to resolve the issue, here is the code that I made for reference:

   ```
   $start-date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tarikh_mula));
   $end-date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tarikh_akhir)); 
   if($start-date > $end-date ){ 
       echo "input date is incorrect";
   }
   ```

Comment: Variable names cannot have dashes in them

Comment: sorry.. the actual is $start_date and $end_date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare dates in PHP, the greater-than sign won't work (it will evaluate them as strings).  Try this function: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
<?php
$date1 = date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2 = date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff = date_diff($date1, $date2);
if ($diff > 0) ... // date1 is earlier than date2
else ... // date2 is earlier than date1
?>
```

Comment: thanks..that means I have to use var_dump($start-date > $end-date) and make the if..else condition. Is that the right way?

Comment: thanks for the help! issue is solve

Comment: You don't actually tell them what's wrong with their code

Comment: He was using a greater-than instead of the date_diff function but he has it working now.